# Why do I have a white area at the bottom of the page when I zoom out?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. When I zoom out on my site, there is a white area at the bottom of the page that appears. I would like to make my web page adapt when I zoom out. How to do it please I don't understand. I did some research, some led me to flex:1; others at min_height:100%... But it doesn't work on my page. Maybe it's the background that I used that really isn't suitable. Here is the link to the site: https://adalonely.go.yj.fr/index.html

I tried using the flex:1; command lines. and min-height:100%; I tried to put them in html,body {}
I asked on discord servers but no answers.
I had the problem of white borders on the sides which I fixed but I have the impression that this problem has nothing to do with it

Comment: Please review the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552)

Comment: What do you want to happen when the user zooms out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to **accueil.css** file and put this codes in the beginning:

```
hmtl, body{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column
}
main{
    flex: 1 !important;
}
```

i tried it and worked, if didn't work clear your cache in the page (using CTRL+F5)